# Google api authentication window closed callback

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to get the contacts from google using javascript api:

```
$(document).on('click', '#connect_to_google', function() {
    $('body').addClass('loading');
    var config = {
        client_id: GOOGLE_CP_CIENT_ID,
        scope: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
    };

    gapi.auth.init(function() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
            var token = gapi.auth.getToken();

            if (null !== token && (typeof token.access_token !== 'undefined')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token + "&alt=json&v=3.0",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //doStuff(data);
                        $('body').removeClass('loading');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, error) {
                        $('body').removeClass('loading');
                    },
                    complete: function (xhr, error) {
                        $('body').removeClass('loading');
                    }
                });

            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('loading');
            }

        });         

    });
});
```

The moment the client clicks the login button, the page displays a layer over it (`$('body').addClass('loading');`), to restrict any user interaction outside google auth page.
All works well, except for the situation when the user closes the google auth window manually, then nothing happens.
Is there any way to check if the user closed that window, to call the `$('body').removeClass('loading');`?

Or is there any way to open the gapi.auth.authorize window in a modal dialog container? That way I could very easy check it's status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
(function(wrapped) {
    window.open = function() {
        var win = wrapped.apply(this, arguments);
        var i = setInterval(function() {
            if (win.closed) {
                clearInterval(i);
                $('body').removeClass('loading');
            }
        }, 100);
    };
})(window.open);
```

It's not the best solution, but it does the work